# How to change the axis label direction on a circular plot in R

Tags: r, plot, angle

I have some angular data (on a scale of `0°`-`360°`). I have successfully created a circular plot using the 'circular' package in `R`, but the axis labels read in an anticlockwise direction, rather than clockwise.

I need to rectify this as the data and axis labels are currently mismatched. **The labels should run from `0°`-`345°` in a clockwise direction.**

Here is the `R` code that I used to create the plot:

```
library(circular)
# Create circular object / Sample Data
df <- structure(c(345, 355, 351, 359, 358, 359, 359, 357, 352, 3, 6, 
4, 342, 336, 349, 352, 340, 354, 335, 348, 355, 353, 354, 346, 
351, 359, 358, 357, 348, 336, 349, 351, 355, 354, 356), .Dim = c(35L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "Bearing"), circularp = structure(list(
type = "angles", units = "degrees", template = "none", modulo = "2pi", 
zero = 0, rotation = "clock"), .Names = c("type", "units", 
"template", "modulo", "zero", "rotation")), class = c("circular", 
"matrix"))

# circular mean
m.p = mean(df)
# mean vector length
rho.p = rho.circular(df)
# label seq for axes values 
p.axis = seq(0,345, by=15)
# axis intervals
a.p <- circular(p.axis, units='degrees', modulo="2pi", rotation="clock")

par(mfrow=c(1,1), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(df, 
 stack=TRUE, 
 bins=60, 
 col="mediumseagreen", 
 pch=16, 
 tcl=0.04, 
 tcl.text=0.125, 
 axes=FALSE, 
 cex=1.4, 
 shrink=1.3, 
 sep=0.05, 
 xlim = c(0, 1.2), 
 ylim = c(-1, 1))
# add axis
axis.circular(a.p, labels=p.axis, cex=0.9) 
# add kernel density estimate
lines(density(df, bw=20), col='mediumseagreen', lty=2, lwd=1.5) 
# arrow to indicate direction of circular mean, scaled by mean vector length
arrows.circular(m.p, shrink=rho.p, length=0.15, col='mediumseagreen', lwd=2.5)
```

I’ve tried fiddling with the code, and have had no luck.

Comment: +1 for the introduction to the package.

Comment: When I run this code, the labels run clockwise.

Comment: @AndreSilva yup, that's exactly what I got.

Comment: @ Brandon & Andre, thanks for your responses. I am complete baffled. I just re-ran the above code to check and I still get anticlockwise labels (see https://www.dropbox.com/s/379neutznswnbue/Test%20image.png). Any ideas or what may be going on?!

Comment: That's wild. I'd blame the magnetic poles if you were in Australia but I'm pretty sure that only works for flushing the toilet. Although, have you tried `rotation="counter"` just for shits and gigs?

Comment: @ Brandon, !!! yep I tried counter. Just reinstalling the package incase of bugs.

Comment: Right, I guess there was a glitch with the package installation or something as I reinstalled it and now I get the correct direction! Apologies for the pointless question. Maybe someone will come across the same thing in the future! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appeared to be an issue with the package rather than the code. Upon uninstalling and reinstalling the circular package the axis labels read in a clockwise direction when using the commands listed above.